# Serializer not working in custom method in model viewset,

Tags: django, serialization

This is my custom method in model viewset.

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @action(detail=False, methods=['POST'],serializer_class=UserSerializer, name='Attach meta items ids')
    def create_user(self, request):
       queryset = User.objects.all() 
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is my serialzer

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    print("lklml")
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("hjniknjbj")
        if UserModel.objects.filter(email=validated_data['email']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("A user is already registered with this e-mail address.")

        if UserModel.objects.filter(
                username=validated_data['username']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This username already exists.")
        user = UserModel.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        # add custom password password validation later
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ("id", "username", "password", "email",)
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {'write_only': True}}
```

Now when ever i hit the api it's directly returning data what i sent and not going through serializer process i.e: returning same thing which i am posting.The issue is only when i am using custom viewset method.

```
{"username":"pragghgjhhhkhhhhjbjhjhkjbjvin","email":"pravwnkwin@dat.com","password":"kms@1234"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `serializer.save()` to call the create function of serializer. `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` is only to run the validator and if all the validation is passed then call `serializer.save()` which will call your create() and return the created instance which can be accessed by calling serializer.data.